# Converting date/selecting date from and to SQL in vb6?

Tags: sql-server, date, select, time

I pulled a date from SQL SERVER with the original format 2015-11-29 15:22:26.000. I needed to show this date to user in a flex grid so i converted it to this format mm/dd/yyyy using this function in my SELECT statement

```
convert(varchar, tblTest_Apointment.AppDate, 101) --> MM/DD/YYYY
```

Ok, now what I need to do is

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Apointment from TblTest_Apointment WHERE apointment = '" & CDate(Me.fgrdApointment.TextMatrix(m_SelectedRow, 2)) & "'"
```

I need to run this statement, however, when I do, because the date is formatted like this mm/dd/yyyy and the I'm using textmatrix, it is unable to pull anything from the table because of incorrect format. How can I convert it to its old state, so it has time stamp on it?

Comment: have 2 columns. one with the original value, and one with the formated date.

Comment: or better yet, just format the date going into the grid in your program.